# Integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of a function: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of $xe^{-x^2}$.

Now I know if the integral from $a$ to $\infty$ of $f(x) dx$ and $-\infty$ to $a$ are convergent, then I could find the integral by summing the integrals from $-\infty$ to $a$ and the one from $a$ to $\infty$. But I tried to start the problem and I got $\infty$ when trying to evaluate from $t$ to $0$, using limits to replace $-\infty$ with $t$. How do I solve this??

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

Comment: See also: [Convergence or divergence integral question: $\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2177957).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't get infinity at either limit.  Maybe you used $e^{(-x)^2}$.  You should be able to use the substitution $u=x^2$ successfully.

Comment: Just a word of caution here: the integral should be broken up at some point because evaluating at the endpoints causes a little bit of a problem if one is not careful.

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$f(x) = xe^{-x^2}$$

is an **odd** function, that is

$$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

or still

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\ \text{d}x = 0$$

Thence

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x = 0$$

**Remark**

This is not a really general result. Not every odd functions are integrable.

Comment: You should be careful with this argument. You're implicitly doing a sort of Cauchy principal value here.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You're right.. maybe I should say that for this kind of integrals, it works, but it's not a really general thing..