# Convergence or divergence integral question: $\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\infty}_{-\infty} x\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$  Determine whether the integral is divergent or convergent.

Hi, I don't have any idea how to start. Should I start with evaluating the integral?

Comment: yes, that would be a good start

Comment: and observe that the Integrand is odd

Comment: Notice that there is no singularity. So, you only need to analyze infinities. Notice that $|x|<e^{x^2/2}$ when $|x|>R$, some fixed R. This tells you that at infinities, your integrand is bounded by an integrable (=with finite integral) function. Done!

Comment: See also: [Integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of a function: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x e^{-x^2}\ \text{d}x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1651366).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac12 e^{-x^2}+C$.  Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x^2}\,dx&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_0^Le^{-x^2}\,dx+\lim_{M\to -\infty}\int_M^0 e^{-x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\left.\left(-\frac12 e^{-x^2}\right)\right|_{x=0}^{x=L}+\lim_{M\to -\infty}\left.\left(-\frac12 e^{-x^2}\right)\right|_{x=M}^{x=0}\\\\
&=\frac12-\frac12\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Ant Thank you for the best vote!  Much appreciative.  Since you're new to the site, I wanted to let you know that after you have enough reputation points you'll be able to up vote also!  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-x^2}$ belongs to the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and so does $xe^{-x^2}$. In particular, $f(x)=x e^{-x^2}$ is an integrable function over $\mathbb{R}$. Since it is an odd function, its integral is zero.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the integral converges if both improper integrals in the right-hand side converge:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}\,\mbox{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{0} xe^{-x^2}\,\mbox{d}x+\int_{0}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}\,\mbox{d}x$$
For either of those (the work is similar for the other one), direct computation is straightforward:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}\,\mbox{d}x = \lim_{p \to \infty}\int_{0}^{p} xe^{-x^2}\,\mbox{d}x$$
Take $u=-x^2$.